# How to create a test suite in selenium webdriver using eclipse ide

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I am using TestNG framework and automating my application. So the structure of my test cases is as below. all the test cases is written in this one method. step by step I tried to write different methods for different test case but then every time webdriver goes to that method it will open a new browser window with that url. I the test case methods to use the same URL which has been opened first time. please let me know how to write test cases in single class and also how to write test suite in test ng. If i am using test ng framework; should i also use any other framework with it.

Comment: What is `that url`??? Please restructure ur question so that we can understand it more clearly... If u r looking to continue all you METHODS in side a CLASS on same browser window...then use @BeforeClass where u will create a driver...and in @AfterClass destroy it...though not recommended as each test method (here test case) should be independent...but use might vary...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a common driver class like the one below in the same package or different package (If you wish to keep it separate).Using this class you can create a driver instance through which u can run all your testcases without opening a new window

```
public class Driver {

    public static WebDriver driver=null;    

    public static WebDriver startdriver(String browser){


        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")){

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/ss4u/Desktop/Vignesh/jars/chromedriver");

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 

        options.addArguments("--test-type"); 

        driver=new ChromeDriver(options);

        }else if(browser.equals("Firefox")){

        driver=new FirefoxDriver();

        }
        return driver;

        }
}
```

If your planning to write your testcase in same class then use the @BeforeTest annotation and create the driver instance

```
@BeforeTest
public static void Openbrowser() {

    Driver.startdriver("chrome");

}
```

You have to use the created driver instance by using the classname

Ex:

```
Driver.driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

And after finishing the test you can close the driver  using @AfterTest annotations

```
@AfterTest
    public static void closebrowser() {

        Driver.driver.quit();

    }
```

@BeforeTest :The annotated method will be run only once before the first test method in the current class is invoked.

@AfterTest : The annotated method will be run only once after all the test methods in the current class have run.

If you want to create more classes and run it as a testng test suite then use the below annotations

@BeforeSuite : The annotated method will be run only once before all tests in this suite have run.

@AfterSuite : The annotated method will be run only once after all tests in this suite have run.

If you wish to run it as a testng suite you have to create a testng.xml file in which you have to define all the classes.visit the below link for testng xml documentation

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml